# Using matrices to solve system of linear equations

Tags: matrices

The question is from JEE Mains 2018. Here it is:

If the system of linear equations
$$x + ky + 3z = 0$$
$$3x + ky – 2z = 0$$
$$2x + 4y – 3z = 0$$
has a non-zero solution $(x, y, z)$, then $\frac{xz}{y^2}$ is equal to :
$(1) 30$
$(2) -30$
$(3) -10$
$(4)  10$

In the solution given, the determinant of matrix formed from the coefficients of $x,y,z$ in the three equations is equated to $0$ and the corresponding value for $k$ is found.

However, as far as I know the condition for non-zero solutions is that the determinant must not equal $0.$ Is there anything I am missing? I am not asking for the solution.  I only need some clarity in the concept. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is the link for the solutions. The question number is $36$:
https://files.askiitians.com/static/jee-main-2018-solutions-code-b.pdf
[sol](https://files.askiitians.com/static/jee-main-2018-solutions-code-b.pdf)
[sol](https://files.askiitians.com/static/jee-main-2018-solutions-code-b.pdf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The zero vector is always a solution to a homogeneos system. It is the unique solution when the determinant of $A$ is non-zero and the matrix is non-singular.

To have a non-zero (non-trivial) solution, the determinant must be zero. In fact, we are going to have infinitely many solutions. The corresponding matrix is singular.

For example, in one dimensional case, $ax=0$. If $a \ne 0$, then $x=0$ is the unique solution. If $a=0$, then any non-zero $x$ is a solution.

Answer (score 2):

You got it the other way round. The correct statement is: $$\det(A) = 0 \Leftrightarrow \ker(A) \text{ non-trivial}\quad (*)$$

You assume the existence of a non-zero solution $(x, y, z)^T$ and you want to compute $\dfrac{xz}{y^2}$. For the computation you essentially need some kind of equation relating $x, y, z$ to each other. For this, you use $(x, y, z) \in \ker(A)$. Unfortunately, you do neither know $\ker(A)$ nor can you compute it without first eliminating $k$.
Fortunately, though, we can apply equation $(*)$ since we assumed the existence of a nonzero solution, i.e. a non-trivial kernel. Equating $\det(A) = 0$ implies $k = \text{ ???}$ (a specific real number) in your case. Now apply the ideas above.